# AWS EC2 - starting T2 unlimited instances - bug in EC2 API?

Tags: amazon-ec2

T2 instances can now be started with an additional option to allow more CPU bursting for additional cost.
SDK: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-ec2-2016-11-15.html#runinstances

I tried it, I can switch my instances to unlimited so it should be possible.
However, I added the new configuration option to the array and nothing changed, it's still set to "standard" as before.

Here a JSON dump of the runinstances option array:

```
{
"UserData": "....",
"SecurityGroupIds": [
    "sg-04df967f"
],
"InstanceType": "t2.micro",
"ImageId": "ami-4e3a4051",
"MaxCount": 1,
"MinCount": 1,
"SubnetId": "subnet-22ec130c",
"Tags": [
    {
        "Key": "task",
        "Value": "test"
    },
    {
        "Key": "Name",
        "Value": "unlimitedtest"
    }
],
"InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior": "terminate",
"CreditSpecification": {
    "CpuCredits": "unlimited"
}
```

}

It starts the EC2 instance successfully just as before, however the CreditSpecification setting is ignored.
Amazon denies normal users to contact support, so I hope maybe someone here has a clue about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm... Using qualitatively the same run-instances JSON

```
{
"ImageId": "ami-bf4193c7",
"InstanceType": "t2.micro",
"CreditSpecification": {
    "CpuCredits": "unlimited"
}
```

}

worked for me - the instance shows this:

```
 T2 Unlimited  Enabled
```

in the "description" tab after selecting this instance in the ec2 console.

Comment: Seems like I had to update the SDK to make it work.
I did not expect that as it's just a variable in an array, would normally not need an update.